# Discrete 3D plots of median ratios of two 2D matrices of lists of values

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation, matrix, probability-or-statistics

Lets say I have 2 2D arrays where each cell contains a list of values:

Example:

```
data_1[[1]][[1]] = {1,2,3} 
data_1[[1]][[2]] = {1,2,3} 
data_1[[2]][[1]] = {1,2,3} 
data_1[[1]][[2]] = {1,2,3} 

data_2[[1]][[1]] = {2,4,6} 
data_2[[1]][[2]] = {3,6,9} 
data_2[[2]][[1]] = {4,8,12} 
data_2[[2]][[2]] = {5,10,15}
```

What's a neat way to make a discrete 3D plot of the ratio between medians of these data sets (assuming that the indices always mach, but can represent any value, not only consecutive natural numbers).For the following data I would expect a plot of:

```
x,y,z
1,1,2
1,2,3
2,1,4
2,2,5
```

Comment: You cannot use underscore (`_`) in symbol names; it is reserved for patterns.  Also, your format is confusing.  Why don't you paste the complete nested list structure you are describing instead of the messy `Set` lines?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard thx for the heads up about "_". I didn't paste it because I don't have it yet -> see my other question [link](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/19008/neat-way-of-extracting-data-from-multiple-csv-with-structured-names)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 dt1 = Array[RandomReal[1, {3}] &, {5, 5}];
 dt2 = Array[RandomReal[1, {3}] &, {5, 5}];
 {med1, med2} = Map[Median, #, {2}] & /@ {dt1, dt2};
 medratios = med1/med2;
 Row[ListPlot3D[#, BoxRatios -> 1, ImageSize -> 300] & /@ {med1, med2,  medratios},
 Spacer[5]
```

[image]

**Update:** per op's request in the comments, here is a version that generates data of the form `{{x,y,{z1,z2,z3}}...`:

```
 dt1xyz = Array[{10 #1, 100 #2, RandomReal[1, {3}]} &, {5, 5}];
 dt2xyz = Array[{10 #1, 100 #2, RandomReal[1, {3}]} &, {5, 5}];
 med1xyz = dt1xyz;
 med1xyz[[All, All, 3]] = Map[Median, med1xyz[[All, All, 3]], {2}];
 med2xyz = dt2xyz;
 med2xyz[[All, All, 3]] = Map[Median, med2xyz[[All, All, 3]], {2}];
 ratiosxyz = dt2xyz;
 ratiosxyz[[All, All, 3]] = 
 med1xyz[[All, All, 3]]/med2xyz[[All, All, 3]]
```

.. and plots:

```
 Row[ListPlot3D[#, BoxRatios -> 1, ImageSize -> 300] & /@ {Join @@ 
  med1xyz, Join @@ med2xyz, Join @@ ratiosxyz}, Spacer[5]]
```

[image]

Comment: will it handle non consecutive indices? like when x has step of 10 and y of 100; (data[[10]][[100]]). Are list suitable for this kind of indexing anyway?

Comment: @JohnnyM, x and y indices need not be consecutive; `ListPlot3D` also takes data in the form `{{x1,y1,z1},{x2,y2,z2}...}`.

Comment: @kugler can you please update your answer so it would generate data in this format?

Comment: @JohnnyM, please see my update.